# For a given number A, find the smallest integer B such that A divides B! (B factorial)

Tags: algorithm

`A` is given such that `A = X^Y` for some positive `X` and `Y`.

Constraints:

```
1 <= Y <= 30000
1 <= X <= 1000000000 (10^9)
```

Test Cases

```
X = 2 and Y = 2. 
Minimum value of B is 4 (as B! = 4! = 24, A = X^Y = 4 and B! % A = 24 % 4 = 0)

X = 2 and Y = 3. 
Minimum value of B is 4 (as B! = 4! = 24, A = X^Y = 8 and B! % A = 24 % 8 = 0)

X = 1000000000 and Y = 30000. 
Minimum value of B is 1080015
```

Link to the Question: https://codefights.com/challenge/XPjFvvKW4kk35jeLp

Comment: off-topic for SO, since this is not a programming, but a math question. Write down how  factorial with each number decomposed into prime factors. You'll immediately see your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could factor `X^Y`. First factor `X`:

```
X = p1^e1 * ... * pk^ek
```

Then `X^Y` will be:

```
X^Y = p1^(e1*Y) * ... * pk^(ek*Y)
```

Then you could binary search `B`: for a fixed value, find out how many times each prime factor `p` of `X^Y` appears in `B!`. This is equal to:

```
floor(B / p) + floor(B / (p^2)) + ...
```

Which you can implement like this:

```
count(B, p):
  s = 0

  while B != 0:
      s += B / p
      B /= p

  return s
```

If this function returns `>= ei*Y` for each prime factor `pi` of `X^Y`, this `B` value is viable: reduce the search in the lower half to see if you can find a smaller one. Otherwise, reduce the search to the upper half.

The problem statement says `B` will fit in an integer, let's assume a 64 bit one. That means at most `64` iterations of the binary search. `X` up until `10^9` can only have around `20` prime factors, and the `count` function runs in `O(log B)`. So expect to do around `64*20*64` operations, plus the few ones required for the initial factorization. Should run very fast.

Comment: binary search is too hard to write